# Moving file from Local c drive to hdfs sandbox

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

i am trying to move file from my local machine to hdfs sandbox but getting error.

command: `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal \c:\tmp\filename.xls hdfs://sandbox:8020/zynga/logs/pv_extA`

error :

```
copyFromLocal: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:tmpfilename.xls
Usage: java FsShell [-copyFromLocal <localsrc> ... <dst>]
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyFromLocal` means the local file system of the Sandbox, not an external file system such as your C: drive. You need to move the file into the Sandbox, either by SCP or other means, and then the `copyFromLocal` will work.